# trusted connection

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

I logged on as administrator and created a trusted connection for a software that connects to my sqlserver.
Then I logged on as a regular user and checked on the db server the users connected.
Surprise: the user logged on was the administrator (the one that configured the connection) and not the current log-on user.
Is it a "trusted connection" feature? I suspect that this behavior is introduced by my software.
thanks in advance
Agostino

Answer (score 0):

I would check the application initiating the connection has not got a hard coded database username/password that it is using to connect

Answer (score 0):

> Whether the connection is to be a
>   secure connection or not. Recognized
>   values are 'true', 'false', and
>   'sspi', which is equivalent to 'true'.

[Reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords)

Basically, you are telling the application to impersonate the current logged on user's identity when connecting to SQL Server, instead of using a specific identity (username/password) in the connection string

> Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial
>   Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated
>   Security=SSPI;
>
> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

If you need to pass a specific username/password then use

> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User
>   ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;

Now, to test for problems, try

1. Change the server name in the connection string and open the app. If the app runs then, as @beakersoft said, perhaps the app is using a hardcoded connection string.
2. Try a specific connection and use "sa" as a test and see if that works. Then try another user.

Note: The username/password (or TRUSTED USER) must have the correct permissions on SQL Server.